# Whats a good character limit for the firstname, username and lastname field for a social networking site?

Tags: mysql

Whats a good character limit for the firstname, username and lastname field for a social networking site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give them 25 chart, for username/first/last name.
**VARCHAR(25)**
Should be pretty enough.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a VARCHAR field in MySQL, it will use either one or two bytes of overhead for a column, depending on whether the size of the field is less than or greater than 255.

So, whether you use 30 or 50 or 255 characters, there is the same 1 byte overhead, and additional storage is only allocated for the characters you actually use.  Given that, I would suggest using 255 unless you have some reason to limit it to fewer characters (e.g. your UI won't handle names that long correctly).

Comment: Do you have a corroborating link for this please

Comment: @CodeBlend - Sure, see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 2):

Interesting topic. First of all, using `VARCHAR` you don't care about wasting characters since strings shorter than the maximum won't occupy all of the buffer. So, don't worry about lower bound of limit.

About upper limit, common sense may help you, but there are extreme and **rare** [cases](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081022055524AAXVIOc) in which your limit is not enough.

I suggest you to use 255 characters to happily sleep at night. It should be a reasonable limit, but **that** guy could find problems signing up to your social network

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to impose a limit?

If so, then I'd not go lower than 32, and probably I'd allow 64 for each.

Answer (score 0):

640kB should be enough for anybody.

Comment: KB ?? I'd say 255 bytes each.